# The graph is strange ( tensorflow-gpu )

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

The graph is strange

I have run the source to test the GPU.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import time

def get_times(maximum_time):

    device_times = {
        "/gpu:0":[],
        "/cpu:0":[]
    }
    matrix_sizes = range(500,50000,50)

    for size in matrix_sizes:
        for device_name in device_times.keys():

            print("####### Calculating on the " + device_name + " #######")

            shape = (size,size)
            data_type = tf.float16
            with tf.device(device_name):
                r1 = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=data_type)
                r2 = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=data_type)
                dot_operation = tf.matmul(r2, r1)


            with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as session:
                    start_time = time.time()
                    result = session.run(dot_operation)
                    time_taken = time.time() - start_time
                    print(result)
                    device_times[device_name].append(time_taken)

            print(device_times)

            if time_taken > maximum_time:
                return device_times, matrix_sizes


device_times, matrix_sizes = get_times(1.5)
gpu_times = device_times["/gpu:0"]
cpu_times = device_times["/cpu:0"]

plt.plot(matrix_sizes[:len(gpu_times)], gpu_times, 'o-')
plt.plot(matrix_sizes[:len(cpu_times)], cpu_times, 'o-')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.xlabel('Matrix size')
plt.show()
```

The GPU's speed continues to increase; the original graph shows very little increase in speed.

It's a development environment.
Python 3.7.0 ( anaconda3 5.3.1 )
CUDA 10.1
Cudnn 7.5.1

[My experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyjJJ.png)

[Original chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PYnt.png)

Comment: Except for anomaly in 500-550 matrix size range, I don't see any speed increase neither in GPU nor in CPU plots. Where do you see constant GPU speed increase ?

Comment: The result should come out in picture number 2, but it looks like picture number 1. What's the problem?

Comment: Still, nothing extra-ordinary in your own graph. Except, that it shows bigger non-linearity in CPU plot, which means that your CPU is next-gen with more ticks per second. And GPU line's very small slope means that your graphics card is also next-gen too and probably has more cores than original experiment's machine. Still, work time increases for a GPU too, so no any speedup here with increasing matrix size

Comment: What exact results do you expect ?

Comment: In the original graph, the GPU does not rise above 0.1 speed. But on my graph, the GPU goes up to 0.8. I want to know what the problem is.

Comment: Firstly, on Y axis there is a relative processing **TIME**, not speed. Second,- I see in your chart that CPU processing time raises to ~ 1.5 and GPU goes up to ~ 0.05. Maybe you had in mind other charts ?

Comment: Name has been changed. Original Chart is my chart. Sorry

Comment: Then your computer is worse compared to original one :-). What exact video card do you have ?

Comment: My Graphic card is RTX 2080.  I don't know why graphic cards do not work so well.

Comment: Hm, that's really strange - your card is bleeding edge. Try to plot charts with data_type `float32` and `float64` and see what happens.